# Using href TO exploit XSS

Tags: iframe, xss, html-helper

Every time I try to inject javascript:alert(1) into the href , the website encodes the special characters < : > and when I try to encode it in html the website deletes the encoding and everything after it

the element when try put a normal ( javascript:alert(1) )

```
<a class="primary-navigation-action more js-analytics-event at-element-click-tracking" href="https://www.target.com/?trk=javascript%3aalert(1)&amp;src=direct%2Fnone&amp;veh=direct%2Fnone%7Cdirect%2Fnone" target="_blank" data-analytics-config="{&quot;category&quot;:&quot;External target&quot;,&quot;action&quot;:&quot;click - Create campaign&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;https://www.target.com/?trk=lms-7-5 - header&quot;,&quot;componentId&quot;:&quot;actionable-content_1395275809&quot;}">
Click here
</a>
```

and this when try to encode the special character by HTML ( : ) after this the website delete the encode character and delete every thing after it

```
<a class="primary-navigation-action more js-analytics-event" href="https://www.target.com/accounts?src=direct%2Fnone&amp;veh=direct%2Fnone%7Cdirect%2Fnone&amp;trk=javascript" title="Create ad" target="_blank" data-analytics-config="{&quot;category&quot;:&quot;External target&quot;,&quot;action&quot;:&quot;click - Create ad&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;https://www.target.com/accounts - header&quot;,&quot;componentId&quot;:&quot;actionable-content_1011291329&quot;}">
Click here
</a>
```

If anyone has a solution to this problem, please help.

Thanks

Comment: What is a `herf`? [The Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=herf) tells me it's some sort of meeting to smoke cigars. Do you mean `href`?

Comment: Sorry, I was typing too fast , I mean href